# Page not printed by Laserjet 5L / 6L until next page is sent (USB parallel port)

Tags: printing, hp, parallel-port

I have a Laserjet 5L (and 6L) connected to a Debian machine. It's detected correctly, but strangely, a page sent to the printer is not actually printed until the next page is sent. Same result by writing directly to /dev/usb/lp0, so seems not to be CUPS-related.

Could it be a buffering problem, or dropped characters?

I also in a few cases get "@PJL SETMPTRAY ..." etc printed when trying to print PDF, which seems to indicate that the printer did not get the whole preamble, or was in the wrong state somehow. But as said, tried with two printers (5L and 6L) with equal results.

**Example**

```
cat > /dev/usb/lp0
FOO
^L
```

(with ^D to finish) nothing happens ...

Trying again:

```
cat > /dev/usb/lp0
BAR
^L
```

"FOO" is printed on a page.

**System information**

Devuan ascii (debian 9)

```
uname -a
Linux diana 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsusb
...
Bus 003 Device 110: ID 067b:2305 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2305 Parallel Port
...
```

Comment: Is your printer connected via a *parallel* port, as lsusb says? Is `/dev/usb/lp0` perhaps a Unix socket connected to a program translating to whatever the native printer language is?

Comment: did you try to print with `lp` command?

Comment: /dev/usb/lp0 is provided by the kernel driver for usb-to-parallel adapters. There should certainly be no high-level content translation. The native language used is PCL, which is what the CUPS drivers output.